# Django queryset.first bug? May involve django-polymorphic and mixins

Tags: python, django, mixins

I have a model, and I have instantiated several instances and persisted them to the database. Through the python shell I can confirm that the objects exist, but I run into trouble as soon as I try to work with the queryset via the `queryset.first()` call, as well as indexing into the `queryset.all()` result. I'm using the `django-polymorphic` plugin.

```
>>> Thing.objects.all()
[<Thing: thing1>, <Thing: thing2>, <Thing: thing3>]
>>> Thing.objects.first()
>>> str(Thing.objects.first())
'None'
>>> Thing.objects.all()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> Thing.objects.all().__class__
<class 'polymorphic.query.PolymorphicQuerySet'>
>>>
```

I strongly suspect this involves the fact that I'm using a mixin for `Thing` on top of the polymorphic base class. Here's what my hierarchy looks like (boiled down to make it easier for y'all):

```
from django.db import models
from polymorphic.polymorphic_model import PolymorphicModel

class AwesomeMixin(object):
    def reallyUsefulMethod(self):
        print('show me your MOVES')

class BaseThing(PolymorphicModel, AwesomeMixin):
    pass

class Thing(BaseThing):
    pass

class Doohickey(BaseThing):
    pass

class SomethingElse(models.Model, AwesomeMixin):
    pass
```

Anyone know what's going on here? Am I using mixins correctly? Is the issue related to `django-polymorphic`? Thanks!

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you updated the settings file as shown in https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?

Comment: I was actually missing the `'polymorphic'` entry in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but after adding it the problem persists. At least you've probably saved me from some future problems!

Comment: Make sure you're also including 'django.contrib.contenttypes' in your INSTALLED_APPS as well. You will also need to do a `./manage.py migrate` after that to make sure the internal models they use are synced.